# Сложение двух массивов разной размерности

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Как правильно складывать массивы разной размерности?
Есть два `numpy` массива. Массив **Wjout** имеет размерность [100, 100], а массив **DW** имеет размерность [100:1]. Массив **DW** складывается с одной колонкой массива **Wjout**.

```
Wjout[:,n] = Wjout[:,n] + DW
```

При выполнении интерпретатор выдает следующею ошибку:

> Wjout[:,n] = Wjout[:,n] + DW
>   ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,100) into shape (100)

Comment: Приведите тестовый пример и желаемый результат. Не 100*100, конечно же, хватит и 5*5.

Comment: Можете вывести `shape` для `Wjout` и `DW`? Потому что приведеный вами код будет работать для размерностей (100, 100) и (100, 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Wjout[:,n] += DW.ravel()
```

Пример:

```
In [92]: a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

In [93]: b = np.random.randint(10, size=3)[:, None]

In [94]: a
Out[94]:
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [95]: b
Out[95]:
array([[7],
       [7],
       [2]])

In [96]: a[:, 2] += b.ravel()

In [97]: a
Out[97]:
array([[ 0,  1,  9],
       [ 3,  4, 12],
       [ 6,  7, 10]])
```

Comment: Все заработало. Большое спасибо! Не в первый раз Вы помогаете решить мне проблемы с кодом.

Comment: @АлексейВоронов, всегда рад помочь :)